# How to adapt on-click JS code for all elements with different classes? (Keeping one element in Bootstrap's Accordion open.)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, accordion

So i took bootstraps accordions and panels to feature different products. I already found the code that allows me to keep one element open, in the thread: "[How do you make Twitter Bootstrap Accordion keep one group open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725717/how-do-you-make-twitter-bootstrap-accordion-keep-one-group-open)" (Thanks for [Hugo Dozois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452289/hugo-dozois) for his answer there!)

```
$('.panel-heading a').on('click',function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.panel').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Since i am using the buttons for the accordion panels outside of the panels themselves, grouped under them, i adapted the code as the following:

```
$('a.btn-600').on('click',function(e){
    if($('.panel-600').children('.panel-collapse').hasClass('in')){
        e.stopPropagation(),
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And this is working just fine. But because i grouped the buttons under the panels, i needed specific classes (for the different product sizes) for them to work. So now i have that code copied 7 times, for example as a btn-750 and panel-750 version as well.

**My Question now is:**

Can i make one function that operates for all of them?

i.e. i want to make the js to take the button's or panel's "product-size-number" and change the function to work like the specific "600"-product size code as above.

The resoning behind this is: in the future there will be coming more product sizes in the future. I would need to add the new size in the .js again an again.

Since i am relatively new to Javascript i wasn't able to find a solution by myself. The closest i got were those three threads: 
[use one function to different elements javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291716/use-one-function-to-different-elements-javascript), [How to use the same JavaScript Function on Multiple Select elements with different ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102578/how-to-use-the-same-javascript-function-on-multiple-select-elements-with-differe)
and [Javascript function on multiple elements at one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773248/javascript-function-on-multiple-elements-at-one-page)

Either those topics dont fit, or i dont know hot to adapt them to my problem.

Would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Try adding working fiddle here (with code attempted by you)!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9owf0w2t/1/ this is a working fiddle, exactly like i used it in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code works for you!

```
$('a.btn-circle').on('click',function(e){
    if($($(this).attr('href')).hasClass('in')){
       e.stopPropagation(),
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, it really works. Thanks man! How does the function operate now, does the beginning of the if condition look at the content of the button's href and finds the target?
Am i right that the class btn-{number} is obsolete then?

Comment: Yes, button has the the same target for which your are checking the `in` class, so without using any numbering we can get the target element.